# Laravel mcamara/laravel-localization package overrides config('app.locale')

Tags: laravel, localization

I'm trying "mcamara/laravel-localization" package to localize my app and it works as expected except for one small issue, the package seems to override the `config('app.locale')` default value.
For instance if the default value of the `locale` property in `config\app.php` file is set to `en` end I changed the application language to french with the language switcher then `config('app.locale')` is evaluated to `fr` instead of the default `en`.

I hope the issue is clear so my question is: how can get the default locale as defined the `config\app.php` config file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the current language code, write the following function:

```
app()->getLocale();
```

In order to activate the activation of a new language, you can write the following function:

```
app()->setLocale('fr');
```

Answer (score 2):

whole point of that package is changing locale, no matter what the default locale is that package change it to whatever you config it to.
but you can get current locale anytime you want using  `currentLocale()` method of App facade and change it with  `setLocale($yourLocale)`.